# Valores retornados em comparação de strings em C

Tags: c, array, string

Estava lendo sobre umas funções do *header* `string.h` em http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/ e me deparei com umas funções de comparação entre *strings* (bem úteis, afinal), como, por exemplo, `strcmp(string1, string2)`.

Dependendo do primeiro caractere que não bate, ou seja, é diferente, a string1 tem um "valor" maior ou menor que a `string2`. Fiquei encucado com isso, então resolvi testar neste código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
     char teste[10];
     char teste2[10];

     printf("teste: ");
     scanf("%9[^\n]", teste);

     printf("teste2: ");
     scanf(" %9[^\n]", teste2);

     printf("%d", strcmp(teste, teste2));

     return 0;
}
```

Quando são iguais é retornado o valor 0 (como está especificado em http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/). Contudo, não consegui compreender o porquê de outros valores. O valor retornado é a diferença dos caracteres segundo a tabela ASCII? Senão, como a atribuição de valores funciona?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conforme a [documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) retorna negativo se o primeiro argumento vem antes do segundo comparando a lexicografia (ordem alfabética) do texto, e receberá um positivo maior que zero se ele vier depois do segundo argumento.

Cada implementação é livre para colocar o número que quiser ali e podem contar a distância, quantas caracteres demora para dar diferença, qualquer coisa. O fato é que não deve trabalhar com esse detalhe, geralmente você só quer saber se é igual ou diferente, e em alguns casos qual deles vem anates do outro, mas não sobre diferenças específicas. Portanto só verifique se é menor que 0, exatamente 0 ou se é maior que 0.

Answer (score 1):

O @Maniero já disse basicamente tudo o que havia para dizer, mas aproveito para por a tabela de retornos que está na documentação que você linkou (traduzida por mim):

```
____________________________________________________________________________________
| retorno | significado
| < 0     | O primeiro caratere que é diferente tem valor menor em str1 do que str2
| 0       | O conteudo de ambas as strings é igual                            
| > 0     | O primeiro caratere que é diferente tem valor maior em str1 do que str2
___________________________________________________________________________________
```

Em que `str1` e `str2` são os dois parâmetros da função:

```
int strcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );
```

Repare que é só isto que está lá escrito em relação ao retorno. Por isso qualquer outra interpretação que faça, já está a interpretar coisas a mais, que potencialmente são detalhes de implementação.